# Copying matrix using text import wizard in Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, excel-import

I am copying some values from Maple software. It will give the values as
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
This has to be copied in excel as

```
[[1    2    3    4]
[2    3    4    5]
[3    4    5    6]]
```

So we can replace [ and ] easily.  I tried text import wizard with delimiter ','. It is displaying like this:

```
   [[1    2    3    4]    [2    3    4    5]    [3    4    5    6]]
```

All rows are appearing in a single row. How to get the required format?

Comment: Seems like this might be an **XY** problem. You write that you want to *replace [ and ] *. If that is the case, what do you really want for a final result?  The numbers alone with each comma separated digit in a single column?  or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use notepad++, paste the above text. replace all "[" with "\n". and replace "]" with "" (nothing).

Then copy all & paste in excel, with "," as delimiter. ( :